# why free function pointers are always of type pointer, whereas member function pointers aren't actually pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am puzzled by the way that C++ treats function pointers and member function pointers, so I distill my doubts in this example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

struct asd{ void f(){ } };
void f(){}

template<typename T> void g(T f){
    cout<<"T of g is "<<
            (is_pointer<T>::value?"pointer":
                    (is_function<T>::value?"function":
                            (is_member_function_pointer<T>::value?"member function pointer":
                                    "something else")))<<" -------- ";

    typedef typename remove_pointer<T>::type TlessPointer;
    cout<<"T of g less a pointer is "<<
            (is_pointer<TlessPointer>::value?"pointer":
                    (is_function<TlessPointer>::value?"function":
                            (is_member_function_pointer<TlessPointer>::value?"member function pointer":
                                    "something else")))<<endl;
}

int main(){
    cout<<"free function ";
    g(f);
    cout<<endl<<"(multiple times) dereferenced free function (!!!) ";
    g(******f);
    cout<<endl<<"member function ";
    g(&asd::f);
    //this won't compile: g(*&asd::f);
}
```

This code prints:

> free function T of g is pointer -------- T of g less a pointer is
>   function
>
> (multiple times) dereferenced free function (!!!) T of g is pointer
>   -------- T of g less a pointer is function
>
> member function T of g is member function pointer -------- T of g less
>   a pointer is member function pointer

So (forgive me once for the openness of the question): why functions and function pointers are treated so differently, that is, why the former are threated as true pointers whereas the latter? Are there historical reasons?

Comment: It's not historical reasons. It is technical reasons. Think virtual functions, (multiple) inheritance and runtime polymorphism

Comment: [Pointers to member functions are strange animals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx)

Comment: I think the historical part of it is that C had already defined function types, but they're essentially useless and so C++ didn't introduce member-function types, only pointer-to-member-function types.

Comment: @Als, do you know something gcc-specific?

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: Whether they are implemented differently or not, they will still not be mere pointers. They *can't* be just a pointer and still be able to do what C++ requires them to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, C++ derived from C, and tries to be compatible in the
common features.  With regards to functions, C is a bit ambiguous with
regards to the distinction between the functions themselves and pointers
to functions: the name of a function converts to a pointer to function
unless it is immediately followed by a '(' token, and a pointer to
function accepts the '(' operator, exactly like a function does.  For 
compatibility reasons, C++ does the same.

Compatibility with C doesn't come into play for member functions, so C++
does things correctly with them: a function is not a pointer to a
function, and there's no reason for an implicit conversion between them.

(Since then, STL has leveraged off the fact that you can
“call” a pointer to function, so that you can use functions
(or rather pointers to functions) as callable objects.)

Comment: could you give me an example of this '(' operator? I cannot understand where I should put this single (?) parenthesis.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: That's just referring to the normal function call syntax; the expression `f()` denotes a function call, and the expression `f` denotes a function pointer, whether `f` is a function or a function pointer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That's the basic effect, anyway.  Formally, the standard says that when `f` is followed by a `(`, the function to pointer conversion is suppressed.  It then goes on to say that the operand to the left of the `(` can be either a function or a pointer to function.  The resulting behavior is very, very similar to that of `a[]`, where `a` is an array type; why the language used to describe it is so different is beyond me.

Comment: this answer has two bugs: In C, the conversion actually is done when it is followed by a '(' (in a call). Actually the function call semantics in C is only defined for function pointers and not for function designators. C++ on the other side is explicit that the function to pointer conversion is *not* done when the function is called (and hence it describes semantics also for lvalues of function type). The second bug is that it says C++ does the same, but C++ only does the conversion when actually needed. For instance, it doesn't do it here `void g() {} void(&f)() = g;` or here `&(e ? f : g);`

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I had some vague memories of the function call operator only being defined on pointers to functions, with an implicit conversion (a bit like what happens with arrays and the `[]` operator), but the only standards I have on line are the C++ ones, and they don't define it this way.  And that's a good point about the conversion only occurring when needed.

Answer (score 6):

A pointer to member function has to work correctly if the function is virtual. In that case, it can't simply be a pointer to the function, since it must dispatch to a different function depending on the dynamic type of the object it's applied to.

It will typically contain:

- A flag to indicate whether it's virtual;
- If non-virtual, a "normal" function pointer;
- If virtual, the index of the function in the vtable (assuming virtual dispatch is implemented with a table).

Comment: In most cases I've seen, a sentinel value has been used as the flag: either a null normal function pointer, to signal that the function is virtual, or something like -1 as the index in the vtable, to signal that it isn't.